# In an HSV image, is it possible to get rid altogether of value?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm training a SVM to detect differences in chlorophyll content in same-species plants.

For one of the steps in the process, I need to convert the RGB to HSV and then use just the hue and saturation channels. JPGs and similar formats just accept RGB (3 channels) or grayscale.

Many thanks in advance.[image: Process flow]

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. You can always convert to HSV and just use the Hue and Saturation channels. What are you having a problem with?

Comment: you want to save the files as 2-channel matrices to save disk space and preprocessing time? You can always write your own data format or openCV fileStorage... I would not use lossy compression (like jpeg) for this task

Comment: Depending on your aim, you could just set the whole value channel to 0 for each image, this should not distract the svm but intriduces some overhead compared to 2 channel input.